# Emacs Package Management

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I used the [package.el for emacs-23](http://bit.ly/pkg-el23) file provided by [technomancy on github](https://github.com/technomancy/package.el) and while I'm able to list the packages, whenever press "i" to install the package emacs simply moves the cursor to the next line. When I press "enter" on the package a new buffer opens showing an "install" button. When I click the button it downloads the package file/directory but doesn't seem to install it. For example, when I tried to install color-theme it downloaded the color-theme directory (and files) but I can't set or use color theme. Anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Since the migration of GNU Emacs to Git all references to blobs on SVN-derived Git repos have changed.  The new URL for the last emacs-23 compatible package.el is:  <http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el>

Comment: Both of these links appear to be dead.  I found http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el from the Emacs 23 section at http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA

Answer (score 1):

I know it doesn't exactly answer your specific question, but I have had a wonderful time using [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get) to install and manage elisp code in my emacs install.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following steps work fine.  Mark packages using the 'i' key -- letter 'I' appears at the front of each package.  Then press the 'x' key to install marked packages.

Comment: That is what OP apparently already did and really equivalent to the steps performed in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Emacs 23, you have to add a "require" to your init.el file.

To enable color-theme, you would add (require 'color-theme) to your init.el. I also downloaded a specific color theme (the wombat theme) and enabled it by having the line (color-theme-wombat) under the require line.

That way, Emacs always loads up with the wombat color theme.

I believe, this is not necessary in Emacs 24, and all this happens automatically.